# How do I access JQgrid ajax return data on every grid reload with a custom function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have overloaded the jqGrid data structure that is returned via the AJAX call to contain extra information I need for my web app on each grid reload.

Every time the grid is loaded/reloaded, I want to be able to access that data and do some manipulation to other DOM elements outside the jqgrid via a function.

I have tried succes/afterSubmit and I don't think they are what I want, because they don't seem to have access to the json returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the data inside of `loadComplete` or `beforeProcessing` callback. The fist parameter represent the data returned from the server in exactly the same form as it was on the server. Inside of `beforeProcessing` callback you can even modify the data in any way.

One more good place for extra information is `userdata` part of the server response (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#user_data)). Additional `userdata` property must be object. The main advantage of the usage of `userdata` is saving of the value of `userdata` inside of `userData` internal parameter of jqGrid. So you can use `getGridParam` to access the data.